# Cannot display png image in html with PHP

Tags: php, image, gd

Despite the numerous attempts at trying to get this to work I'm stumped.  I have explained in many other posts that I am very new to PHP and unfamiliar with the vast capabilities and know that I've almost got this to work but just can't seem to make it happen.  I've already had one very helpful person try to dumb it down for me [a link] https://stackoverflow.com/a/13872071/1880796 but now I just need someone to correct an error in my code to get it to work.  I think there is something wrong at the end of the url because when I try to view the image and look at the url its all messed up so I don't know what I'm doing wrong.  I've double and triple checked all the math because it is so confusing but here is the result.php:

```
<?php
    $filename = "Results.txt";
    $lines = file($filename);

    $q1 = $_POST['q1']; // stores checked button value
    $q2 = $_POST['q2'];
    $q3 = $_POST['q3'];
    $q4 = $_POST['q4'];
    $q5 = $_POST['q5'];
    $q6 = $_POST['q6'];
    $q7 = $_POST['q7'];
    $q8 = $_POST['q8'];

    $qN = 1;  //question number

    $newLines = '';

    $total = array();

        foreach($lines as $line) {

            $line = trim($line);  //remove excess newlines etc.
            $lineArr = explode(',',$line);  //split line into array by commas
            $index = ${'q'.$qN}-1; //zero based
        if (isset($lineArr[$index])){
            $lineArr[$index]++;  //add to position by one vote.
            $total = array_sum($lineArr); //number of clicks 

            $newLines .= implode(',',$lineArr) . "\r\n"; //newLines contains numbers then also
        $qN++;
        }
    }
//write contents back to file.
file_put_contents($filename, $newLines);

//frequencies for each line without strings
$l[1] = explode(',',$lines[0]);
$l[2] = explode(',',$lines[1]);
$l[3] = explode(',',$lines[2]);
$l[4] = explode(',',$lines[3]);
$l[5] = explode(',',$lines[4]);
$l[6] = explode(',',$lines[5]);
$l[7] = explode(',',$lines[6]);
$l[8] = explode(',',$lines[7]);

//multiply each 
$result = array();
$values = array(1,2,3,4,5);
for($i=0;$i<count($l);$i++){
    for($j=0;$j<count($values);$j++){
    $result[$i+1][$j] = $l[$i+1][$j] * $values[$j];
    }
}
//calculate percentages

$p1 = (explode(',',$lines[0]));
$p2 = (explode(',',$lines[1]));
$p3 = (explode(',',$lines[2]));
$p4 = (explode(',',$lines[3]));
$p5 = (explode(',',$lines[4]));
$p6 = (explode(',',$lines[5]));
$p7 = (explode(',',$lines[6]));
$p8 = (explode(',',$lines[7]));

// calculate averages *****For some reason most recent frequency item updated is off by one, possibly bc not up to date yet???? figure out later!!!
$f1avg = round((array_sum($result[1])/($total-1)),2);
$f2avg = round((array_sum($result[2])/($total-1)),2);
$f3avg = round((array_sum($result[3])/($total-1)),2);
$f4avg = round((array_sum($result[4])/($total-1)),2);
$f5avg = round((array_sum($result[5])/($total-1)),2);
$f6avg = round((array_sum($result[6])/($total-1)),2);
$f7avg = round((array_sum($result[7])/($total-1)),2);
$f8avg = round((array_sum($result[8])/($total-1)),2);
//pie chart question 1 information
$p1f0 = round((($p1[0]/($total-1))*360),0);
$p1f1 = round((($p1[1]/($total-1))*360),0);
$p1f2 = round((($p1[2]/($total-1))*360),0);
$p1f3 = round((($p1[3]/($total-1))*360),0);
$p1f4 = round((($p1[4]/($total-1))*360),0);
//_____________$a0________$a1______________$a2___________________$a3__________________________$a4_______________
$pC1 = array(($p1f0),($p1f0+$p1f1),($p1f0+$p1f1+$p1f2),($p1f0+$p1f1+$p1f2+$p1f3),($p1f0+$p1f1+$p1f2+$p1f3+$p1f4));
print_r ($pC1);
```

And here is the pie chart script:

```
header("Content-type: image/png");

//create pie charts
$image=imagecreatetruecolor(51,51);
//_____________________colors____________________________
$my_colorA=imagecolorallocate($image,51,51,255);
$my_colorB=imagecolorallocate($image,100,150,215);
$my_colorC=imagecolorallocate($image,20,20,151);
$my_colorX=imagecolorallocate($image,216,216,255);


$red = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 0, 0);
$orange = imagecolorallocate($image, 191, 64, 0);
$dark_yellow = imagecolorallocate($image, 128, 128, 0);
$dark_green = imagecolorallocate($image, 64, 191, 0);
$green = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 255, 0);
//_______________________________________________________
imagefill($image,0,0,$my_colorX);

//__________________ , center,  w , h , st, end, clr  ,    type______
imagefilledarc($image,25,25, 50, 50,  0,  $a0, $red, IMG_ARC_PIE);
imagefilledarc($image,25,25, 50, 50, $a0,  $a1, $orange, IMG_ARC_PIE);
imagefilledarc($image,25,25, 50, 50, $a1, $a2, $dark_yellow , IMG_ARC_PIE);
imagefilledarc($image,25,25, 50, 50, $a2,  $a3, $dark_green, IMG_ARC_PIE);
imagefilledarc($image,25,25, 50, 50, $a3,  $a4, $green, IMG_ARC_PIE);
//___________________________________________________________________

imagepng($image);
imagedestroy($image);
```

I have no idea why it isn't working but when I click view image i get this:
PieChart.php?a0=33&a1=66&a2=230&a3=263&a4=361/%3E%3C/td%3E%3Ctd%20style=

so yeah I don't know what I'm doing wrong!  Please help!

Oh and lastly this is what I'm putting into my html.

img src=\"PieChart.php?a0=".$pC1[0]."&a1=".$pC1[1]. "&a2=".$pC1[2]. "&a3=".$pC1[3]."&a4=".$pC1[4]."/"

and yes I'm aware it needs the img tag and php and echo i just couldn't post it in the form.

Comment: yes that is what i thought to, so i tried changing imagepng($image); to imagepng($image,"myimage.png"); and found that it was generating the image and in the right path i believe.

Comment: Sorry, deleted the comment, I looked closer at your problem and felt it was not relevant. My newest concern is the call to PieChart.php where you're getting some leaking html. The `%3E$3C/td...` portion of the URI seems to hint that part of your table is being output to the URL.

Comment: yes I just fixed that and now when i go to view image it gives me this instead /PieChart.php?a0=15&a1=30&a2=285&a3=300&a4=360

Comment: also i want to correct myself and say that I'm not 100% sure that it was actually printing out images because those files i had could have been from other attempts and just left there.

Comment: newest update, piechart file even with hard coded values is only printing a circle in the color of the last imagefilledarc() function...

Comment: It works perfectly for me if I copy paste your code and use the given values: http://i.imgur.com/QN1mg.png. How are you hard-coding those values?

Comment: yeah the hard coding is working fine at this point I just tried that too i think it has something to do with passing values from text/html to image/png

Comment: The text/html sending data to the .php file shouldn't matter so long as you're reading them properly from the parameters. Your computer/browser only cares about the data stream the web server sends back which you've declared as a png. What happens before is none of your browser's concern. How are you taking the parameters into variables in the code, I don't see it there.

Comment: sorry i missed that part,
header("Content-type: image/png");
$a0 = $_GET['a0'];
$a1 = $_GET['a1'];
$a2 = $_GET['a2'];
$a3 = $_GET['a3'];
$a4 = $_GET['a4'];

Comment: Hey its working now and i think because I was missing a ; at the end and i had it right from the start but i just wasn't printing!  Thanks a million to everyone that helped, and also I'm new to this site so if there is a way to give credit or rep to people just let me know what i need to do.

Comment: Still works fine for me. You haven't omitted anything that might be altering those values? Does your webserver have any rewrite rules on .htaccess possibly messing up the script? Is the file blocked by permissions?

Comment: I'd have to submit an answer and you select it as the solved one (checkmark below it). It helps people who come along to your question and get the answer themselves. I'll just summarize our discussion. Merry Christmas/Happy Holidays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution happened to be a syntax error of some form but for anyone coming looking for insight on the code above...

1) Check the script by hard coding the input values and viewing the result.
2) Check the parameters being passed from your calling function.

After that, the code sample above is extremely similar to one you'll find in the php manual.